# Multiplying with weights

Tags: r

I have two data structures. One is a data frame with forecasts and another is a named vector with forecast weights. I'd like to use the weights to multiply each forecast according to it's weight and ensemble the data.

Seems like a simple task, but I wanted to test it out first.

```
df = data.frame(one=c(100,300,400,600,300,400), two=c(500,500,500,500,500,500), 
                three=c(50,30,40,50,60,70), four=c(2,5,3,4,3,3))
df
v = c(one=0.20,two=0.20,three=0.30,four=0.40)
df*v
```

That was simple. However, when I attempt to apply the same principle to my data, it pukes in the following way.

```
> point_forecasts * best_forecast_weights[, grep("forc_", colnames(best_forecast_weights))]
Error in Ops.data.frame(point_forecasts, best_forecast_weights[, grep("forc_",  : 
  ‘*’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

Any suggestions on how this can't be extended to my real data.

The two are of different dimension, but so was my sample from earlier.

```
> dim(point_forecasts)
[1] 12 12
> dim(best_forecast_weights[, grep("forc_", colnames(best_forecast_weights))])
[1]  1 12
```

Here is the data.

```
> dput(best_forecast_weights)
structure(list(forc_ses = 0.117817985571929, forc_ets = 0.0161288086012641, 
    forc_aa = 0.117805724951262, forc_aaf = 0.118799383174985, 
    forc_hw = 0.0451599619363367, forc_nn = 0.111375507054973, 
    forc_lm = 0.0662063818276547, forc_bsts = 0.0818938829947608, 
    forc_mavg = 0.0172445767409558, forc_hybrid = 0.136259607040553, 
    forc_cr = 0.0534757012899833, forc_struc = 0.117832478815342, 
    scheme = "variance based", dim_names = "lmosconsolidatedcustomerid ", 
    dim_values = "USA_1760"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), .Names = c("forc_ses", "forc_ets", "forc_aa", "forc_aaf", 
"forc_hw", "forc_nn", "forc_lm", "forc_bsts", "forc_mavg", "forc_hybrid", 
"forc_cr", "forc_struc", "scheme", "dim_names", "dim_values"))
> dput(point_forecasts)
structure(list(forc_ses = c(4408.4307495589, 4408.4307495589, 
4408.4307495589, 4408.4307495589, 4408.4307495589, 4408.4307495589, 
4408.4307495589, 4408.4307495589, 4408.4307495589, 4408.4307495589, 
4408.4307495589, 4408.4307495589), forc_ets = c(3014.28888364505, 
2463.93355789192, 1913.57823213878, 1363.22290638565, 812.867580632516, 
262.512254879383, -287.84307087375, -838.198396626883, -1388.55372238002, 
-1938.90904813315, -2489.26437388628, -3039.61969963941), forc_aa = c(4408.00532266543, 
4408.00532266543, 4408.00532266543, 4408.00532266543, 4408.00532266543, 
4408.00532266543, 4408.00532266543, 4408.00532266543, 4408.00532266543, 
4408.00532266543, 4408.00532266543, 4408.00532266543), forc_aaf = c(4361.78033632219, 
3847.04682861951, 3467.29642894454, 3283.58737770275, 3315.39477841926, 
3559.8292879854, 3987.97423641516, 4521.56378153502, 5016.78121920777, 
5297.45842132112, 5246.63539901233, 4886.37690151687), forc_hw = c(1996.86969056628, 
6438.80091882798, 730.499044737788, -695.596151211418, -3247.24176869611, 
-11.1251796965471, -339.345816659107, 2520.85448419972, 5704.86448715835, 
1795.80340575535, 467.497302543252, -2666.36819973286), forc_nn = c(7570.40440833295, 
7817.51208686512, 7774.78545565402, 6600.84174499494, 6427.19186182921, 
7697.04750040604, 7659.83514954764, 6556.86171233771, 7656.46367244252, 
6335.78196983503, 7641.79649846112, 6529.91387555727), forc_lm = c(13049.1884247555, 
14145.1312730948, 9803.74999022683, 1457.80533427488, 6772.01950249792, 
9981.31995200218, 9275.1827480621, 9561.780834832, 8276.59378982876, 
6950.99104996345, 9168.51040241743, 5946.64813505662), forc_bsts = c(6489.80885158037, 
5805.89878415257, 4021.73099992211, 1231.97020036671, 2741.04687738945, 
3477.56186323454, 3426.2302905591, 3618.57762773849, 3028.2472483372, 
2539.42006616604, 3523.78089091349, 2085.06547360143), forc_mavg = c(2993.75545382493, 
2475.93427620301, 1958.11309858108, 1440.29192095916, 922.470743337232, 
404.649565715306, -113.171611906619, -630.992789528545, -1148.81396715047, 
-1666.6351447724, -2184.45632239432, -2702.27750001625), forc_hybrid = c(5681.15230426712, 
6068.70892040052, 4381.18430142845, 4489.14083401097, 3910.57834895585, 
4981.67550749813, 4589.50962898391, 6251.06924846359, 5220.83840646985, 
5044.82310488863, 4702.63185462144, 4518.96804448667), forc_cr = c(8395.46737804888, 
8395.46737804888, 8395.46737804888, 8395.46737804888, 8395.46737804888, 
8395.46737804888, 8395.46737804888, 8395.46737804888, 8395.46737804888, 
8395.46737804888, 8395.46737804888, 8395.46737804888), forc_struc = c(4408.93379287327, 
4408.93379287327, 4408.93379287327, 4408.93379287327, 4408.93379287327, 
4408.93379287327, 4408.93379287327, 4408.93379287327, 4408.93379287327, 
4408.93379287327, 4408.93379287327, 4408.93379287327)), .Names = c("forc_ses", 
"forc_ets", "forc_aa", "forc_aaf", "forc_hw", "forc_nn", "forc_lm", 
"forc_bsts", "forc_mavg", "forc_hybrid", "forc_cr", "forc_struc"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Going to my original example, the goal is to have one ensemble forecast such as the following

```
> (df[1,1]*v[1] + df[1,2]*v[2] + df[1,3]*v[3] + df[1,4]*v[4])/4
  one 
33.95
```

Comment: Are you sure `df*v` works the way you think it does in your simple example? I think that you think it's multiplying the `one` column by the `one` entry in the vector, the `two` column by the `two` entry, etc. That is not the case. The `v` vector is recycled over rows...

Answer (score 0):

Look into the documentation for `?sweep`, it helps in this case. The data frame of weights should be coerced to a vector with `unlist`:

```
sweep(point_forecasts, 2, unlist(best_forecast_weights[-(13:15)]), '*')
#    forc_ses   forc_ets  forc_aa forc_aaf      forc_hw  forc_nn   forc_lm forc_bsts  forc_mavg forc_hybrid
# 1  519.3924  48.616888 519.2883 518.1768   90.1785592 843.1576 863.93955  531.4756  51.626046    774.1116
# 2  519.3924  39.740313 519.2883 457.0268  290.7760044 870.6794 936.49796  475.4676  42.696439    826.9199
# 3  519.3924  30.863737 519.2883 411.9127   32.9893091 865.9207 649.07082  329.3552  33.766832    596.9785
# 4  519.3924  21.987161 519.2883 390.0882  -31.4130957 735.1721  96.51602  100.8908  24.837225    611.6886
# 5  519.3924  13.110586 519.2883 393.8669 -146.6453147 715.8318 448.35091  224.4750  15.907618    532.8539
# 6  519.3924   4.234010 519.2883 422.9055   -0.5024127 857.2626 660.82708  284.7910   6.978010    678.8011
```